# Sharepoint Infopath Form

Tags: infopath

Can we submit data to different lists from same InfoPath form?

I am trying to create an InfoPath form which contains fields from two different lists. Can we submit data to two different lists?

Answer (score 0):

I looked for something similar some days ago and found this one:

https://salnikan.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/inserting-multiple-list-items-at-once-into-a-sharepoint-list/

instead of customized the form, start infopath and choose to design a new one in order to have the option to enable “Management multiple list items” capability.

Then you should be able to add a secondary data source to be displayed in a XML file within the infopath form

Comment: Please avoid just posting a link as an answer. Quote the main aspects of the article as well as the links tend to go down.